# Python Django ModuleNotFoundError for modules containing underscores only on CI pipeline

Tags: python, django, import, pipeline, sentry

I have been hitting the ModuleNotFoundError error when I add modules to my project in the requirements.txt file. This seems to only occur with module imports that have an underscore. Namely these two:

- sentry_sdk
- exponent_server_sdk

When I create  virtual environment locally and run server it works without error. When the same process is done as part of my CI pipeline I get:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sentry_sdk'

I have followed the sentry guide for django integration
https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/python/guides/django/

[EDIT]
I'm using [buddy.works](https://buddy.works) as my pipeline. This is the output and traceback.

```
Resolving host ******ENCRYPTED******...
Connected. Executing commands...
cd ******ENCRYPTED******/releases/488
virtualenv --python=python3.6 env
Using base prefix '/usr'
New python executable in ******ENCRYPTED******/releases/488/env/bin/python3.6
Also creating executable in ******ENCRYPTED******/releases/488/env/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pkg_resources, pip, wheel...done.
Running virtualenv with interpreter /usr/bin/python3.6
source env/bin/activate
++ deactivate nondestructive
++ unset -f pydoc
++ '[' -z '' ']'
++ '[' -z '' ']'
++ '[' -n /bin/bash ']'
++ hash -r
++ '[' -z '' ']'
++ unset VIRTUAL_ENV
++ '[' '!' nondestructive = nondestructive ']'
++ VIRTUAL_ENV=******ENCRYPTED******/releases/488/env
++ export VIRTUAL_ENV
++ _OLD_VIRTUAL_PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
++ PATH=******ENCRYPTED******/releases/488/env/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
++ export PATH
++ '[' -z '' ']'
++ '[' -z '' ']'
++ _OLD_VIRTUAL_PS1=
++ '[' x '!=' x ']'
+++ basename ******ENCRYPTED******/releases/488/env
++ PS1='(env) '
++ export PS1
++ alias pydoc
++ '[' -n /bin/bash ']'
++ hash -r
pip3 install -r roundupsapi/requirements.txt
Collecting certifi==2019.11.28
  Using cached certifi-2019.11.28-py2.py3-none-any.whl (156 kB)
Collecting chardet==3.0.4
  Using cached chardet-3.0.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (133 kB)
Collecting Django==2.0.9
  Using cached Django-2.0.9-py3-none-any.whl (7.1 MB)
Collecting django-cors-headers==3.2.0
  Using cached django_cors_headers-3.2.0-py3-none-any.whl (14 kB)
Collecting django-email-utils==0.1.1
  Using cached django_email_utils-0.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (3.9 kB)
Collecting django-rest-email-auth==2.1.0
  Using cached django_rest_email_auth-2.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (42 kB)
Collecting djangorestframework==3.9.4
  Using cached djangorestframework-3.9.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (911 kB)
Collecting idna==2.8
  Using cached idna-2.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl (58 kB)
Collecting protobuf==3.11.2
  Using cached protobuf-3.11.2-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (1.3 MB)
Collecting PyMySQL==0.9.3
  Using cached PyMySQL-0.9.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (47 kB)
Collecting pytz==2019.3
  Using cached pytz-2019.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (509 kB)
Collecting requests==2.22.0
  Using cached requests-2.22.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (57 kB)
Collecting six==1.13.0
  Using cached six-1.13.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (10 kB)
Collecting urllib3==1.25.7
  Using cached urllib3-1.25.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl (125 kB)
Collecting stripe==2.48.0
  Using cached stripe-2.48.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (203 kB)
Collecting sentry_sdk==0.19.2
  Using cached sentry_sdk-0.19.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (127 kB)
Collecting asn1crypto==0.23.0
  Using cached asn1crypto-0.23.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (99 kB)
Collecting cffi==1.14.3
  Using cached cffi-1.14.3-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (400 kB)
Collecting cryptography==3.2.1
  Using cached cryptography-3.2.1-cp35-abi3-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (2.6 MB)
Processing /home/******ENCRYPTED******/.cache/pip/wheels/be/ba/89/4df1a952bcd0716ac1d5f6f051233e1f3a653948f08bc0a7be/pycparser-2.18-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pyOpenSSL==17.5.0
  Using cached pyOpenSSL-17.5.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (53 kB)
Collecting exponent_server_sdk==0.3.1
  Using cached exponent_server_sdk-0.3.1-py3-none-any.whl (7.0 kB)
Collecting aiocontextvars==0.2.2
  Using cached aiocontextvars-0.2.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (4.9 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in ./env/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from protobuf==3.11.2->-r roundupsapi/requirements.txt (line 10)) (50.3.2)
Processing /home/******ENCRYPTED******/.cache/pip/wheels/41/11/53/911724983aa48deb94792432e14e518447212dd6c5477d49d3/contextvars-2.4-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting immutables>=0.9
  Using cached immutables-0.14-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (98 kB)
Installing collected packages: certifi, chardet, pytz, Django, django-cors-headers, django-email-utils, djangorestframework, django-rest-email-auth, idna, six, protobuf, PyMySQL, urllib3, requests, stripe, sentry-sdk, asn1crypto, pycparser, cffi, cryptography, pyOpenSSL, exponent-server-sdk, immutables, contextvars, aiocontextvars
Successfully installed Django-2.0.9 PyMySQL-0.9.3 aiocontextvars-0.2.2 asn1crypto-0.23.0 certifi-2019.11.28 cffi-1.14.3 chardet-3.0.4 contextvars-2.4 cryptography-3.2.1 django-cors-headers-3.2.0 django-email-utils-0.1.1 django-rest-email-auth-2.1.0 djangorestframework-3.9.4 exponent-server-sdk-0.3.1 idna-2.8 immutables-0.14 protobuf-3.11.2 pyOpenSSL-17.5.0 pycparser-2.18 pytz-2019.3 requests-2.22.0 sentry-sdk-0.19.2 six-1.13.0 stripe-2.48.0 urllib3-1.25.7
/usr/bin/python3 roundupsapi/manage.py makemigrations
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "roundupsapi/manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/******ENCRYPTED******/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 371, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/******ENCRYPTED******/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 365, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/******ENCRYPTED******/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 288, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/******ENCRYPTED******/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 332, in execute
    self.check()
  File "/home/******ENCRYPTED******/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 364, in check
    include_******ENCRYPTED******ment_checks=include_******ENCRYPTED******ment_checks,
  File "/home/******ENCRYPTED******/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 351, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "/home/******ENCRYPTED******/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 73, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "/home/******ENCRYPTED******/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 40, in check_url_namespaces_unique
    all_namespaces = _load_all_namespaces(resolver)
  File "/home/******ENCRYPTED******/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 57, in _load_all_namespaces
    url_patterns = getattr(resolver, 'url_patterns', [])
  File "/home/******ENCRYPTED******/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 36, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/******ENCRYPTED******/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 540, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/home/******ENCRYPTED******/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 36, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/******ENCRYPTED******/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 533, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "******ENCRYPTED******/releases/488/roundupsapi/roundupsapi/urls.py", line 26, in <module>
    url(r'^api/roundupusers/', include('roundupusers.urls')),
  File "/home/******ENCRYPTED******/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/conf.py", line 34, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "******ENCRYPTED******/releases/488/roundupsapi/roundupusers/urls.py", line 4, in <module>
    from roundupusers.views import *
  File "******ENCRYPTED******/releases/488/roundupsapi/roundupusers/views.py", line 33, in <module>
    from exponent_server_sdk import (
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'exponent_server_sdk'
```

I Googled around and it doesn't seem to be a common issue. I'm also confused that other modules I have worked with have worked straight away such as stripe. I can only think it has something to do with the underscores?

Or possibly there is an issue with a path somewhere on the CI build.

Any clues is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: At least include the traceback, not just the error message. The import tree is important. And probably any output that your not working buddy provides.

Comment: @Melvyn I have updated the question to include the output and traceback. Thanks

Comment: `/usr/bin/python3 roundupsapi/manage.py makemigrations`  is using the system interpreter , not the venv.

Comment: Is that a simple change I can make? Why does this only effect these modules and not when I have added others? Thanks

Comment: I don't think the underscore is relevant. I'm actually surprised you're getting this far. Cause there's a number of things that don't add up. Like the usage of a virtualenv, but your traceback references files in a user install (`pip install --user <package>`) location. In fact, it looks like there's an old user install and later you decided to switch to virtualenv, but are using it only for install, but not for migration, so those new packages are not there (and happen to have underscores).

Comment: If you don't know how your CI script works, then add it to the question and we'll have a look.

Comment: I agree this feels more of a CI issue and impressed that you correctly diagnosed what happened! We swapped developers during the CI setup and I think it has lead to this downfall. Python and pipelines aren't my bread and butter so I will discuss with a colleague and get back to you. Thanks for your time!

Comment: Hi @Melvyn, working with my colleague we were able to debug the issue you alluded to. We updated the pipeline script so that all the installs are within the virtualenv and so the modules that are installed are available. Thanks for pointing us in the right direction! We are aware that running virtualenv on the server isn't right but this an MVP product and we'll be moving away from this in the near future. Thanks again, this issue is now resolved!